Problems with the animation of my drag & drop interface
The drag and drop animation was expected to happen when trying to move a card from one container to another.
I'm using dnd-kit to build a kanban board, but I'm having problems with the card animation when I try to drag an "item" into another container. The animation of dragging the items while you hold them is not occurring, it is simply jumping from one container to another. The problem is most likely in the "handleDragStart", "handleDragMove" and "handleDragEnd" functions.
// Find the value of the items

function findValueOfItems(id, type) {
    if (type === 'container') {
        return containers.find((item) => item.id === id);
    }
    if (type === 'item') {
        return containers.find((container) =>
            container.items.find((item) => item.id === id),
        );
    }
}

// DND Handlers
const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor),
    useSensor(KeyboardSensor, {
        coordinateGetter: sortableKeyboardCoordinates,
    }),
);

function handleDragStart(event) {
    const { active } = event;
    setActiveId(active.id);
    console.log('Drag Start:', { active });
}

function handleDragMove(event) {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (!over) return;

    const activeContainer = findValueOfItems(active.id, 'item');
    const overContainer = findValueOfItems(over.id, 'container');

    if (!activeContainer || !overContainer) return;

    const activeContainerIndex = containers.findIndex(container => container.id === activeContainer.id);
    const overContainerIndex = containers.findIndex(container => container.id === overContainer.id);

    const activeItemIndex = activeContainer.items.findIndex(item => item.id === active.id);

    if (activeContainerIndex !== overContainerIndex) {
        const newItems = [...containers];
        const [removedItem] = newItems[activeContainerIndex].items.splice(activeItemIndex, 1);
        newItems[overContainerIndex].items.push(removedItem);
        setContainers(newItems);
    }
}

function handleDragEnd(event) {
    const { active, over } = event;

    if (!over) {
        setActiveId(null);
        return;
    }

    const activeContainer = findValueOfItems(active.id, 'item');
    const overContainer = findValueOfItems(over.id, 'item');

    if (!activeContainer || !overContainer) return;

    const activeContainerIndex = containers.findIndex(container => container.id === activeContainer.id);
    const overContainerIndex = containers.findIndex(container => container.id === overContainer.id);

    const activeItemIndex = activeContainer.items.findIndex(item => item.id === active.id);
    const overItemIndex = overContainer.items.findIndex(item => item.id === over.id);

    if (activeContainerIndex === overContainerIndex) {
        const newItems = [...containers];
        newItems[activeContainerIndex].items = arrayMove(
            newItems[activeContainerIndex].items,
            activeItemIndex,
            overItemIndex,
        );
        setContainers(newItems);
    } else {
        const newItems = [...containers];
        const [removedItem] = newItems[activeContainerIndex].items.splice(activeItemIndex, 1);
        newItems[overContainerIndex].items.splice(overItemIndex, 0, removedItem);
        setContainers(newItems);
    }

    setActiveId(null);
}

